# Django: When delete db.sql3 file / new database, cannot create user : save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite, django-2.0

**My aim:**

I want to re-create the django development database from scratch / starting over. I am using Django 2.1.4

**My method:**

- I delete the development database file ( db.sql3 )
- after this, I attempt to re-build the database, by running

  ```
  python manage.py migrate

  python manage.py makemigrations

  python manage.py migrate

  python manage.py createsuperuser
  ```
- I have tried several permutations on above, including: the order of commands, makemigrations on a specific app, create a normal user, deleted all migrations files.

**The result:**

The last step (create user) produces an error which means I cannot create a user for the database, or else work with the database file:

```
    File "/..../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 413, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

**My settings:**

I am using the settings file mostly un-altered save for including those apps I have created under INSTALLED_APPS, but not more than that.

I have one app that creates user profiles:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Profile(models.Model):
          user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

          def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

          def save(self):
            super().save()
```

**My attempts:**

- most posts online related to this is outdated, referencing functionality not current any longer in Django version (2.1.4), such as syncdb.
- I have spent long time trying find "best practice" around resetting your database / drop tables / start over your database, but those posts useful mostly are 5 years old and reference again functionality not present in Django 2 or referencing production database.
- I have re-built my project from scratch 3 times to overcome the problem but I rather try to find a solution to the problem as I anticipate I need to trash/drop/delete the development database file db.sql3 several times more ahead

**Question:**

- Can someone share the best practices around deleting and re-create the database file during development in Django version 2.
- What is the error and how to solve it?

  > TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'.

Comment: What is your actual user model (settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)?

Comment: Hi Ivan, your question solved it, I am using another user model and when I deactivated it, it worked. I complete my question with this info, as I then ask how I need to define my setting file to make it work

Comment: this article helped me a lot: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Comment: Thanks Hugo! I do think the topic is now answered. Ivan gave a hint that the issue was an additional user model, later on I also discovered that any linkage to any database within the code tend to make it messy. So, it seems also to be a bit of an art to do it properly.